# How I get the Customer from payouts data in Shopify? Using payouts Id

Tags: shopify, netsuite

I want to do the integration Shopify to NetSuite.In the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FBUE.png) giving the detail of my payouts api and response data.using that payout id I want pull the customer for that payout to generate the Netsuite deposit record against that customer which is already present in Netsuite account.please suggest me using that id how and which API needs to call to get the customer.

Following is my Response using API

GET/admin/shopify_payments/payouts.json?status=paid

Response :

```
{
    "payouts": [
        {
            "id": 23420993582,
            "status": "paid",
            "date": "2019-01-29",
            "currency": "USD",
            "amount": "46050.05",
            "summary": {
                "adjustments_fee_amount": "0.00",
                "adjustments_gross_amount": "20.62",
                "charges_fee_amount": "1122.23",
                "charges_gross_amount": "48097.76",
                "refunds_fee_amount": "0.00",
                "refunds_gross_amount": "-946.10",
                "reserved_funds_fee_amount": "0.00",
                "reserved_funds_gross_amount": "0.00",
                "retried_payouts_fee_amount": "0.00",
                "retried_payouts_gross_amount": "0.00"
            }
        }
]
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FBUE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you have one payout with id **23420993582**.  What you need to do now is lookup all the transactions related to this payout. These are available at the following resource: 
 GET/admin/shopify_payments/payouts/23420993582/transactions.json

This will return a property in the response called `transactions` which is an array of all the transactions with a `payout_id` of **23420993582**. The first entry (index 0) is not a sales transaction -- it is a summary of the payout (note the type).

You can iterate of this array and use the `source_order_id` of each object to lookup the original order.  In that order is where you will find the customer. Note the `type` of each item in the array. You will see `charge`, `refund`, `payout`, etc).

I also use NetSuite and for me, I was not really interested in finding the customer but rather the order_id.  Since my NetSuite cash sales and refunds have the order_id on them (when they are created) i can match up existing sales and refunds to the NetSuite deposit.  When you link the NetSuite transaction (in `payment` sublist of the deposit record)

Any discrepancies (commissions to shopify, etc) I log in the "other deposits" or "cash back" area of the NetSuite deposit.

Because the NetSuite deposit should have the exact same amount it is wise to total up the NetSuite transaction amount AND the shopify transaction amount.  They should be the same, but things like currency conversion or edits or mistakes can cause the totals to be different and any difference will cause the deposit to not be saved.

If you have any discrepancy in the totals then programmatically create an additional cash back / other deposit entry to offset it.

if you have something to fix it is now clear in the transaction. You can always delete a deposit and redo it after fixing.

Comment: Thanks for answering,I was try your way but not get any orders using  source_order_id     flowing my api  1)GET/admin/shopify_payments/balance/transactions.json?payout_status=paid&payout_id=23420993582      After That  I was try to pull order of  "source_order_id": 873783033902  Api Call Is 2)GET/admin/orders.json?ids=873783033902  I did not get null result. Please can you help me to sort of that issue.

Comment: Do you have permissions to view orders?  What about simply GET/admin/orders/873783033902.json in a browser as a sanity check?

Comment: Yes,I have permissions to view orders,Using  simply GET/admin/orders/873783033902.json  i will get the required result.But Can i achieve the same result using that type of request GET/admin/orders.json?ids=873783033902  because I can easily pass parameters in integrator software.Can You please suggest on that.

Comment: Than you so much gillyspy,Now problem was solve,I am using you're suggested api